# Is Ubuntu compatible with Intel Extreme DZ77GA hardware?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, intel

Well, I installed Windows 8 and found multiple incompatibilities with my hardware. I experienced freezes while shutting down and restarting Windows 8. Does the following hardware combination function fully with Ubuntu without freezing occurring?

My hardware specifications:

- mobo: Intel Extreme DZ77GA 70K
- RAM: 16GB G-Skill Ripjawsx 1866MHz (1.65V)
- HDD 1TB Toshiba MK1002TSKB (7200rpm)
- GPU: 2GB EVGA GT640

Does Ubuntu have drivers for the above specs? Will Ubuntu run smoothly on my machine without any conflicts?

Comment: I want to know about it toooo!

Comment: Try a liveDVD or liveUSB first without installing anything. It's the best way to test.

Answer (score 0):

I will address the ones that matter, which are Motherboard and Video Card (The rest I know they work and will get detected correctly).

**VIDEO** - For the Nvidia card the answer provided in [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/driver-to-use-when-installing-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card) which covers many of the issues Ubuntu users suffer sometimes. Some more than others. But if you do the guide it will save you a lot of trouble.

**MOTHERBOARD** - For any chipset based on the Intel DZ68 or DZ77 it will work out of the box (The ones I have tested so far). There are no issues that I am aware of right now about the DZ77 Chipset (Including the Extreme Editions). What I do suggest is upgrading the firmware for them. They Extreme Editions do get a lot of firmware updates so it is always a good idea to have the latest update.